# Troubleshooting source of computer lockup (hang/deadlock)

Tags: windows-8, freeze, hardware-failure

Recently my desktop has been experiencing random lockups.

By this I define a total system freeze, CTRL+ALT+DEL does nothing, LED's on keyboard don't turn on/off, unplugged/re-plugged mouse & keyboard don't light up/confirm connection (via the desktop sound effect).

SPEC is:

- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
- Mobo: AMD Asus Sabertooth 990FX Rev 1 AM3+
- CPU:  AMD Phenom ii X4 965 BE @ 3.41GHz  (With CM TX3 Hyper Evo Cooler)
- RAM:  2x Corsair Vengeance 4GB  @ 1333MHz (Dual Channel)
- RAM:  2x Corsair Vengeance Pro 4GB  @ 1333MHz (Dual Channel)
- GPU1: AMD Sapphire HD 7770 Flex 1GHz 1GB
- GPU2: AMD XFX HD7770 Series 1GHz  1GB [GPU's In Crossfire]
- PSU:  Cooler Master G650M (650w Bronze 80+ SLI/C-Fire Certified)
- SSD: OCZ Agility 3 60GB
- HDD1: 500GB WD Blue (5400rpm)
- HDD2: 750GB WD Black (7200rpm)
- CD/BluRay: Sony CD Rewriter & LG BluRay Rewriter

I've checked the status of each drive, SSD and HDD2 report no errors, with HDD1 reporting a warning on "Reallocated sectors". This shouldn't be the cause of the lockups as the drive was disconnected before and was only reconnected a day after the lockups began.

Internal Temps seem normal, all range between 30 and 45 degrees centigrade, fans all are spinning with no grinding sounds or shorting sounds.

MemTest86+ reports no errors on any of the sticks of RAM. (Tested each stick one by one)

Wiped and re-installed Windows, installed all updates + required drivers. Lockups are still present.

Lockups are following no fixed procedure, they occur randomly and without warning.

Looking at the above, I believe to have narrowed it down to either the CPU or the Motherboard. Whilst I am not a professional technician, I welcome anothers opinions on this.

---

Update!!

I've removed all drives (Except SSD) and the XFX GPU.

System did freeze after boot up (video output continued, but all inputs ceased). running fur mark seems to be stable on graphics card (max temp of 60c)

Comment: Every HDD I have had in the last 2 decades that had a high amount of reallocated sectors ended up failing eventually, and in nearly every single one of those cases, the system would spend a bunch of time waiting for I/O events to happen.  In other words a high amount of reallocated sectors absolutely would cause the problems you have experienced and has honestly been the ONLY thing that has caused it for me.  Take the mechanical drivers out of the equation to confirm.

Comment: Interesting. I will do so and report back with any further developments

Comment: I've had this problem in the past, and it turned out unexpectedly to be caused by a dodgy graphics card. You have not done any graphics tests, so try running with a single graphics card for a while, to see if the system is then stable: if not try the other graphics card. If it is still unstable then you have at least eliminated that cause.

Comment: if the light doesn't toggle, it is a hardware and no software issue. Remove some RAM sticks and look if you still have issues.

Comment: AFH, noted, I'll try this and see if it still occurs. Thankfully the XFX is still within warranty so if it turns out to be that one it's not so bad.

@magicandre1981, ok, i've tested the RAM and it doesn't show any errors, so how likely it it to be this then?

Comment: Updated question with additional info at bottom.

Comment: Are you using some kind of torrent app/does the lockups occur when You are downloading/play video from web on high definition?

Comment: @divin3 no, I don't torrent and it began when I was playing a game, but since then it mainly happens when on desktop or explorer is open.

Comment: remove some RAM modules. The board seams to have issues when you use all RAM modules.

Comment: Noted. So it's possible I could be looking at a faulty ram slot then? (If this proves to be the case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported Corsair RAM types for your motherboard in 1333 MHz are:

```
Type       Part No.              Size
CORSAIR    TW3X4G1333C9A         4GB ( 2x 2GB )  
CORSAIR    CMX8GX3M2A1333C9(XMP) 8GB ( 2x 4GB )  
CORSAIR    CMX8GX3M4A1333C9      8GB ( 4x 2GB )
```

If I remember right, You can check the Part No. of your RAM with [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/) in the 'SPD' tab

Also make sure that your timing for the RAM is set right in bios: 9-9-9-24; voltage: 1.5
And/Or the XMP profile is set.

check manual for more details:
http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_990FX/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: I've checked the ram and its fine for the motherboard, no issues since install (over 4 months ago) and memtested too, also no issues.

Comment: well my first guess would have been the HDD buffer overloading, since I think that is not an option, it can only be the ram or the video card. Please check the steps I have written in my answer. If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I will do my best to help.

Comment: I will investigate this and report back within findings.

Comment: Switched out the Sapphire GPU for the XFX one, no crash during test in Furmark. Seems almost as if the issue was in the Sapphire Card (it is from Nov 2012)

Comment: Did it crash with the Sapphire?

Comment: Once. I'm just running a couple of further tests to check if this is indeed the case

Comment: Did you check the RAM, we talked earlier about? I have the same problem on my pc. And my best guess is that it is because of the RAM, even if it doesn't fail memtest, the motherboard doesn't like it.

Comment: I took out all RAM modules, re-inserted the older Corsair Vengeance modules and booted. No Crash. Swapped those out with the newer ones and rebooted, no crash, then re-inserted all and rebooted. Thus far no crash has happened.

Comment: When was the last time, that it crashed?

Comment: Last time it crashed was 2 days ago, however the pc was not used yesterday

Comment: My best guess for your problem is still the RAM. This is the first thing that I would want to make sure works fine. I have another question, what programs do you install, after a clean windows install?

Comment: Usually, MS Office, Steam, AMD Catalyst and Antivirus (Although this install currently has none of these installed)

Comment: Yes it is set now.

Comment: One more thing. I see your PC has lots of components in it. Is that PSU enough to power everything?

Comment: Its been enough to power everything for just over a year (with heavy usage) and its never done this before.

Comment: What have you changed in your PC before these lookups started to happen?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.

Comment: I am out of ideas for now. I say, let's wait what happens next. I wonder if the lockups continue after xmp was set. I will do some more research about this. Just leave a comment if it freezes again.

Comment: Are the lookups still present? If not, I wonder how did You solve the problem, and also I would like to ask you to accept the best answer for your question, so this post can be closed. If the problems are still present, than please tell me so I can do some more research.

Comment: HI, Apologies for the serious delay in replying. The lockups are no longer present, and the culprit was identified as a foreign object (likely to be dust) in the motherboard on the PCI-e x16_1 slot.  Removed the GPU and carefully cleaned, then reseated and then the problem was no more. Also to note the XMP settings have helped overall, so will be accepted as best answer. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I'm glad it is now properly working again. At least we learned something new. Thank You for the reply of the solution. Have a nice day.